# How to create rotating trade information view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I am working on a project where my **requirement is to show some information in continuous rotating manner** same as trading information shows all stocks information.Here i am stuck how to do this. Here i am attaching the screen shot of what exactly we need to do.So please help me out to solve this.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Thought about using a scroll view?

Comment: Google "carousel scroll view ios". https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: It's also known as a "marquee" effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using scroll view. If you dont want to write code from scratch, you can use MarqueeLabel control available on github.   https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use iCarousel example with continuos label exchange . or you want circular display the text in a label you can use a thread and updated the values in array and display in the text.